# How to perform grep operation on all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, subdirectory

Working with xenserver, and I want to perform a command on each file that is in a directory, `grep`ping some stuff out of the output of the command and appending it in a file.

I'm clear on the command I want to use and how to `grep` out string(s) as needed.

But what I'm not clear on is how do I have it perform this command on each file, going to the next, until no more files are found.

Answer (score 446):

In Linux, I normally use this command to recursively `grep` for a particular text within a directory:

```sh
grep -rni "string" *
```

where

- `r` = recursive i.e, search subdirectories within the current directory
- `n` = to print the line numbers to `stdout`
- `i` = case insensitive search

Answer (score 349):

`grep $PATTERN *` would be sufficient. By default, grep would skip all subdirectories. However, if you want to grep through them, `grep -r $PATTERN *` is the case.

Comment: "grep -r $PATTERN ." is sufficient. For recursive grep you do not need to specify all files

Comment: How do I include multiple extensions? Eg. "\*.cpp", "\*.h"?

Comment: @Tomáš Zato, just supply all your file patterns instead of *: `grep $PATTERN *.cpp *.h`. If you need more specific rules for what files should be grepped, use `find` command (check Rob's answer).

Comment: @umi If I run `grep -r x .` results come from all files of all extensions. If I run `grep -r x *.scss` than I receive no results.

Comment: @Chris it's possible you don't have `*.scss` files in current directory but somewhere deeper in subdirs so grep does not look in all the files you wanted. You should use `--include` option to tell grep to look recursively for files that matches specific patterns: `grep -r x --include '*.scss' . ` (note the quotes, they prevent the pattern from being expanded by the shell). Or just use `find` (see Rob's answer).

Comment: You want `grep -s` so you don't get a warning for each subdirectory that `grep` skips.  You should probably double-quote `"$PATTERN"` here.

Answer (score 53):

Use find. Seriously, it is the best way because then you can really see what files it's operating on:

```
find . -name "*.sql" -exec grep -H "slow" {} \;
```

Note, the -H is mac-specific, it shows the filename in the results.

Comment: If you decide to use find, pipe the output through `xargs` rather than using `-exec` this will be *much* faster, because `-exec` spawns a new process for each grep, and the overhead becomes significant with a large number of files. Standard warnings about spaces in file names apply to `xargs`.

Comment: What would this look like exactly? I always forget `xargs` syntax.

Comment: @BrianPeterson it would be something like that: `find . -iname "*.sql" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "slow"`

Comment: `grep -r` offers much the same functionality. The OP didn't seem to actually want to traverse subdirectories.

Comment: `-exec` on modern `find` supports shortcutting just like `xargs`, and will actually be faster (because you cut out `xargs`).  Use `-exec ... {} +` instead of `-exec ... {} \;`

Answer (score 22):

To search in all sub-directories, but only in **specific file types**, use grep with `--include`.

For example, searching recursively in current directory, for text in *.yml and *.yaml :

```
grep "text to search" -r . --include=*.{yml,yaml}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do multiple commands, you could use:

```
for I in `ls *.sql`
do
    grep "foo" $I >> foo.log
    grep "bar" $I >> bar.log
done
```

Comment: Generally, probably try http://shellcheck.net/ on the code you post. [Don't use `ls` to expand a wildcard](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (the shell already does it for you!) and [quote your shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: You probably want to use Awk instead for this, especially if the input file is big. `awk '/foo/ { print >"foo.log" } /bar/ { print >"bar.log" }' "$I"` searches for both patterns in a single pass over the input file. (Try `grep -E 'foo|bar' "$I"`if you want to search for multiple patterns, but don't require multiple output files.)

Answer (score 1):

tldr:

```bash
grep -r --include=*.md --include=*.markdown --exclude-dir=node_modules "postgres"
grep -r -o --include=*.md --include=*.markdown --exclude-dir=node_modules "postgres"
```

I'm on Ubuntu using bash with GNU grep 3.7:

```bash
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.7
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I wanted to search for anything in files with a **.md** or a **.markdown** extension.

The first example produced results like this:

```bash
elves/_posts/2023-09-11-postgres.markdown:postgres
elves/_heroku-guide/HerokuDataStarter.md:https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql
elves/_heroku-guide/HerokuDataStarter.md:heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/README.md:# my_gem/db_adapters/postgresql.rb
```

The second:

```bash
elves/_posts/2023-09-11-postgres.markdown:postgres
elves/_heroku-guide/HerokuDataStarter.md:postgres
elves/_heroku-guide/HerokuDataStarter.md:postgres
vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/README.md:postgres
vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/docs/GettingStarted.md:postgres
vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/README.md:postgres
```

I found something like the following helpful:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

GREP='grep -r --include=*.md --include=*.markdown --exclude=bundle.js etc...'
```